# Issue hiding div with 'event.stopPropagation'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

Working on an Ajax cart for Shopify with Cart.JS.

My original code for hiding showing the 'ajaxcart' container where originally:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("lightbox").hide();
    $("ajaxcart").hide();
    $('#button').click(function(event){
        $('lightbox').show().addClass('fadeIn').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        function() {
          $(this).removeClass('fadeIn');
        });
        $('ajaxcart').show().addClass('slideInRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        function() {
          $(this).removeClass('slideInRight');
        });
            event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#button").on("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('lightbox').show().addClass('fadeOut').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        function() {
          $(this).removeClass('fadeOut');
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('ajaxcart').show().addClass('slideOutRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        function() {
          $(this).removeClass('slideOutRight');
          $(this).hide();
        });
    });

    $('ajaxcart').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
});
</script>
```

However, when using the hide parts with `event.stopPropagation();`, it messes up the code to use the cart buttons due to stopping the events.

I have created a live testing so you can see how the buttons in the cart does not respond: https://eldecosmetics.com/pages/bergen

Any ideas how to safely hide the 'ajaxcart' container without stopping the events in the container and the Ajax, and without using the last part with `event.stopPropagation();` which seem to be the problem?

Comment: Assuming that 'ajaxcart' is a custom element, you can hide the element using jQuery hide method. event.stopPropagation(); does not hide an element.                                                    
    $('ajaxcart').click(function(event) {
        $(this).hide();                                                                                   
    });

Comment: @RajeshP I know that, but this doesn't give me the ability to close the 'ajaxcart' only when clicking outside of the 'ajaxcart'. If i remove event.stopPropagation() 'ajaxcart' is closed when clicking on the containera as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('html').click(function()` to hide the div when clicking outside of the 'ajaxcart'. I created a new div with position: absolute; to fill the whole area of the body behind 'ajaxcart'. And then use this to close the 'ajaxcart' instead.

```
$('lightbox').click(function() {
      $('lightbox').show().addClass('fadeOut').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        function() {
          $(this).removeClass('fadeOut');
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $('ajaxcart').show().addClass('slideOutRight').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', 
        function() {
          $(this).removeClass('slideOutRight');
          $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```